# Mongoose Schema Validation not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my model file. I want to Create validation on schema but this will not work for me. I don't know why because this is the standard Implementation. Suggest me, anyone, if I am wrong.

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true// My value is not converted into lowercase
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'User');

router.post('/putname, function(req, res){
  var user = new User({
    username: req.body.username
  });
  user.save(function(err, data){
    if(error) { console.log(error) }
    else { console.log('Entry Inserted Successfully') }
  });
});
```

Comment: It Still doesn't work for me.. I Don't know why. My mongoose version is 4.13.6

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `new` before `mongoose.Schema`. And you can have only parameters inside `mongoose.model`

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true 
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

router.post('/putname, function(req, res){
  var user = new User({
    username: req.body.username
  });
  user.save(function(err, data){
    if(error) { console.log(error) }
    else { console.log('Entry Inserted Successfully') }
  });
});
```

You can also organise your code as:

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({ ... });
```

Comment: I did it as you told. Still my entry enter in Capital case if, means lowercase: true not work. I added new before mongoose.Schema. but problem is same as earlier

Comment: @Abhay does the record inserted in your db?

Comment: Yes. With CAPITAL ENTRY

Comment: I tried with the same code on my side and I am getting  lower case 

`
{
  "_id": "5ab2611d88d6de2d2e3cfacd",
  "updated_at": "2018-03-21T13:44:10.231Z",
  "created_at": "2018-03-21T13:41:49.697Z",
  "some_id": "5a82860aba42f0401c321111",
  "name1": "aaa",
  "name2": "AAA"
  "__v": 1
}
`

Comment: @Abhay my version is "mongoose": "4.9.3"

Comment: mine was 4.13.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167266/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-abhay).